# Taxation for remote workers, if the company and the residency are in different countries

Tags: germany, europe, world

If a contractor or employees works 75%-100% percent remote for a company in a country A and has his residency in a country B - what is the job-related taxation?

I know that this is too general to answer, since it depends on the jurisdictions of the countries involved. But I am specifically looking for answers to the following combinations:

1. Status: Contractor ; Company in: Germany ; Residency: Europe
2. Status: Contractor ; Company in: Germany ; Residency: Outside Europe
3. Status: Employee ; Company in: Germany ; Residency: Europe
4. Status: Employee ; Company in: Germany ; Residency: Outside Europe

Comment: I think it depends mostly on the contract. But for a full time job (employee) it should be that the company pays for the social taxes and you will need to pay for the income in the country of residence. In Europe at least